# wsl 2 ubuntu mariadb .my.cnf.42' is ignored

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mariadb-10.4

So have wsl 2 setup on windows 10, installed ubuntu, imstalled apache.

Windows 10 Version 2004(OS Built 19041.21) / Ubuntu 18.04

Now at the next stage and trying to install mariadb.
Have installed it following the instructions here
https://computingforgeeks.com/install-mariadb-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-centos-7/

Specifically 
 `sudo apt -y install mariadb-server mariadb-client`
Did not get asked for a password, so followed the next step
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`
Where I now get the following error

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
Warning: World-writable config file '/mnt/c/Users/soup/.my.cnf.42' is ignored`
```

It is obviously ignoring /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which have given correct user/rights to (makes no difference if 600, 644, 755)

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
sudo chmod 600 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

And trying to use a windows temp file.
Also when trying 
`sudo service mysql restart` get the message `mysql: unrecognized service`
Something has obviously gone wrong
Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?
thanks

Comment: I have given up one this, and removed mariadb and installed mysql.
This is some sort of wsl error which will no doubt be sorted out in a later release

Completely purged mariadb

  ' sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server


And installed mysql instead

    sudo apt install mysql-server
    sudo mysql_secure_installation
    sudo service mysql start

Answer (score 1):

I have given up one this, and removed mariadb and installed mysql.
This is some sort of wsl error which will no doubt be sorted out in a later release

Completely purged mariadb

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server'
```

And installed mysql instead

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
sudo service mysql start'
```